# Include path in PHP

Tags: php, path, include, absolute-path

here is my folders and files:

```
Folder Main
 folder a
   - fila a.php
 folder b
   - file b.xml
 folder c
   - file c.php
index.php
```

when I try to do this its shows error any suggestion or fixes.

file c.php

```
<?php
class Abc{
public function __construct(){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('b/b.xml');
}}?>
```

so I include file c.php in a.php, which going to show error

```
<?php require '../c/c.php'; $abc = new Abc(); ?>
```

file index.php

```
<?php
   require 'c/c.php';
   $abc = new Abc();
 ?>`
```

but if I include in index.php no prob. How do I fix the path ('b/b.xml') in c.php so that I can include it anywhere in the project.

---

I found the way to fix it. by doing this

file c.php

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/b/b.xml');
```

file a.php

```
include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/c/c.php';
$abc = new Abc();
```

in file index.php

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/c/c.php';
$abc = new Abc();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple idea use in Joomla / Wordpress / Cakephp & other open source.

In your index.php, use:

require( dirname( __ FILE__ ).'/c/c.php');

and in class construction, use:

$xml = simplexml_load_file(dirname( __ FILE__ ) .'/b/b.xml');

Let me know if this works.

Thanks,
Munjal

Comment: I do not face any problem at index.php. The problem is when i run the a.php file.

Comment: simply use dirname( __ FILE__ ) (it's an PHP system variable) which retrieve current folder path.

Comment: its not working i echo the file part i get this: 
/home/u210663092/public_html/main/c/b/b.xml
i want remove the c dir..

Comment: the current folder path is /home/u210663092/public_html/main/c but i'm including file from folder b into folder c files..

Comment: ok. for that, you can use another simple way (which basically use in OPENCART / ZENCART / OSC etc.)


in your config file, use a define variable & call it on include


e.g.


define(DIR_MAIN,'/home/u210663092/public_html/main');

Do let me know if this is better :)

Comment: Finaly found the solution by doing this in: 

file c.php
 
 dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/b/b.xml'
 
file a.php

 include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/c/c.php';
 $abc = new Abc();
 
in file index.php

 require dirname(__FILE__).'/c/c.php';
    $abc = new Abc();

Comment: for better view check back my Q. i cannot answer my own Q not enough rep

Comment: great.
Can you please put '+1' to my answer :)
Thanks

Comment: less 15 rep cant vote deym..once got the rep i will +1

Comment: If you have sufficient rep now, can you please do +1

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the c.php as follows:

```
<?php

     class Abc
        {
            public function __construct()
               {
                 $xml = simplexml_load_file('mainfoldername/b/b.xml');
               }
        }
?>
```